# V8 segfault when calling function - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-ndk, v8, embedded-v8

I had a very old pre-built version of V8 working nicely with an integration into the Android NDK via JNI, and all was well.

I decided to upgrade V8 to more recent code (4.1.0.22), built my own ARM archive files on Ubuntu, and keeping my own architecture the same, I've refactored the code as apparently required by changes in the V8 codebase.

However, it crashes.

The way I want to structure this, maybe unusually compared to some simpler examples, is have a persisted V8 instance that I can initialise once and then make multiple calls to later. Each call provides Javascript code content and a method name (usually 'main').

So, this is effectively my initialisation code, run once:

```
Persistent<Context> exec_context;

Isolate* isolateRef;

Platform* platformRef;

V8Resources(void (&initialiseTemplate)(Isolate* isolate, Handle<ObjectTemplate>))
{
    // Initialize V8.
    V8::InitializeICU();
    platformRef = platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
    V8::InitializePlatform(platformRef);
    V8::Initialize();

    isolateRef = Isolate::New();
    {
        // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
        HandleScope handle_scope(isolateRef);

        //Register for callbacks
        Handle<ObjectTemplate> global_templ = ObjectTemplate::New(isolateRef);
        initialiseTemplate(isolateRef, global_templ);

        Local<Context> local_context = Context::New(isolateRef, NULL, global_templ);
        exec_context.Reset(isolateRef, local_context);

        Context::Scope context_scope(local_context);
    }
}
```

My `V8Resources` object above is what hangs around. This code works OK, as far as I can tell.

Then in the 'run script' method, called some time later, I have this:

```
Isolate* isolate = v8instance->getIsolate();

Locker v8Locker(isolate);

const char *source_str= //...
const char *function_name_str = //...

HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
Local<Context> context = Context::New(isolate);
Context::Scope context_scope(context);
Local<Object> global = context->Global();
TryCatch trycatch(isolate);

Handle<String> js_source = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, source_str);
Handle<Script> js_compiled = Script::Compile(js_source);

if (js_compiled.IsEmpty())
{
    throwNativeException("Error: compiled script is empty!");
    return 0;
}

js_compiled->Run(context);

Handle<String> js_function_name = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, function_name_str);
Handle<Value> js_function_val = global->Get(js_function_name);

Handle<Function> js_func = Handle<Function>::Cast(js_function_val);

Handle<Value> argm[0];

Handle<Value> js_result;
{
    js_result = js_func->Call(global, 0, argm);

    if (js_result.IsEmpty())
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Determined via logging, this blows up with a SIGSEGV at `js_func->Call`, and to the extent that I have anything useful, provides this stack trace:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 000045d0
Stack frame 03-17 15:42:52.168: I/DEBUG(28556):     #00  pc 002b24a0  /data/app-lib/com.myapp.app-43/libv8jsevaluator.so (v8::TryCatch::TryCatch()+52)
Stack frame 03-17 15:42:52.168: I/DEBUG(28556):     #01  pc 0033cfd8  /data/app-lib/com.myapp.app-43/libv8jsevaluator.so (v8::internal::Execution::TryCall(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*, v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object>*)+64)
Stack frame 03-17 15:42:52.168: I/DEBUG(28556):     #02  pc 0034abfc  /data/app-lib/com.myapp.app-43/libv8jsevaluator.so (v8::internal::Factory::NewError(char const*, char const*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+384)
Stack frame 03-17 15:42:52.168: I/DEBUG(28556):     #03  pc 00349da4  /data/app-lib/com.myapp.app-43/libv8jsevaluator.so (v8::internal::Factory::NewError(char const*, char const*, v8::internal::Vector<v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object> >)+372)
Stack frame 03-17 15:42:52.168: I/DEBUG(28556):     #04  pc 00349e90  /data/app-lib/com.myapp.app-43/libv8jsevaluator.so (v8::internal::Factory::NewReferenceError(char const*, v8::internal::Vector<v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object> >)+40)
Stack frame 03-17 15:42:52.168: I/DEBUG(28556):     #05  pc 00429d74  /data/app-lib/com.myapp.app-43/libv8jsevaluator.so (v8::internal::IC::ReferenceError(char const*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>)+76)
Stack frame 03-17 15:42:52.168: I/DEBUG(28556):     #06  pc 0042ce44  /data/app-lib/com.myapp.app-43/libv8jsevaluator.so (v8::internal::LoadIC::Load(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>)+1048)
Stack frame 03-17 15:42:52.168: I/DEBUG(28556):     #07  pc 0042d8a0  /data/app-lib/com.myapp.app-43/libv8jsevaluator.so (v8::internal::LoadIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)+396)
Stack frame 03-17 15:42:52.178: I/DEBUG(28556):     #08  pc 00000090  <unknown>
```

I've played around with this a fair bit - including different TryCatch patterns - but can't get anywhere, and I'm not convinced I'm actually using V8 appropriately.

Is there anything obviously wrong in this description?

Comment: Compile V8 with debug/asserts enabled

Comment: I'll give it a shot and report back - was going to try this earlier but gave up when I saw it was 700MB. What should I expecting to get as a result?

Comment: What was 700mb? Anyway with asserts enabled they will trigger if you are using v8 wrong

Comment: Building android_arm.debug produces about 700MB in .a archive files, although it turns out not to really matter. So anyway, this now produces a SIGABRT relating to `Isolate::GetCurrent()`, which I take to mean I'm misusing that. Still looking into this for now...

Comment: The answer seems to be that a call to Isolate->Enter() was required, but I need a little more time to fully understand this before I answer my own question. Thanks for the debug tip - helped narrow it down significantly.